# Sub String function in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

From the string '000-111-222-333' I need to extract '000-111' alone i.e., part of string before 2nd '-'in Teradata without hardcoding the position since number of characters in the string can vary.Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you already tried, and what are the findings of any research you've done? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your TD release (or installed UDFs):

```
SUBSTRING(x FROM 1 FOR INSTR(x,'-',1,2) - 1)
```

This should work in any TD release:

```
SUBSTRING(x FROM 1 FOR POSITION('-' IN x) + POSITION('-' IN SUBSTRING(x FROM POSITION('-' IN x) + 1)) - 1)
```

Comment: Is there any way to get part of substring based on 3rd occurence?

Comment: What's your TD release?